# How to create an interactive timeline (example site: https://evianexperience.com/en) using SVG - in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, svg, timeline, divi-theme

I am creating a website in WordPress and I am using DIVI theme.

I need help to create an interactive timeline for a project. The example site is: https://evianexperience.com/en. This is the exact thing I want to implement.

Please see me web layout (https://snag.gy/IKF13r.jpg) to get an idea, what actually I need it for.

I have tried to use Interactive Storytelling (https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/12/16/animated-map-path-for-interactive-storytelling/) but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try scroll magic, seems to have plenty of features to achieve what you need.

http://scrollmagic.io/

Also I think skrollr will still work but it's pretty old

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly what they have, looks like they are using some product called greensock, probably even this module: https://greensock.com/drawSVG and also ScrollMagic to control the animation by scrolling. A tutorial I found online with different animation https://ihatetomatoes.net/svg-scrolling-animation-triggered-scrollmagic/

I don't think you could do it with Divi alone, you can definitely try just some scroll plugins which are free. Otherwise you could see if greenstock's free/business license works for your project.